# Is it possible to create a dashed border around text boxes in visual basic.net windows form application?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I've been working with a code that allows me to draw lines around text boxes in vb.net but these lines are solid lines. I'd like to have dashed or even dotted lines to dress the application up a little. Is there a way to make dashed lines around text boxes like you can do on the form? The current code I'm using is as so..

```
Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Aqua, 2.0)
Dim txtBox As Control
  For Each txtBox In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf (txtBox) Is TextBox Then
          g.DrawRectangle(pen, New Rectangle(txtBox.Location, txtBox.Size))
      End If
  Next
pen.Dispose()
```

I wanted to also mention I am able to used this code in the paint event to get a dashed line around my form. It would look really nice to get it around the text boxes too I hope this is possible!

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle,Color.Aqua, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)
```

EDIT: I've just tried this code it seems to be drawing dashed rectangles but they are not going around my textboxes so not sure how to fix it.

```
Dim txtBox As Control
  For Each txtBox In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (txtBox) Is TextBox Then
      ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, txtBox.ClientRectangle, txtBox.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: See [this question on Experts' Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24803642/VB-NET-windows-forms-how-to-make-dotted-or-dashed-borders.html). You might also want to look at [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-borderstyle-property-access). It's strongly recommended that you do some research before posting your question on the StackExchange network; I found both of those in less than a minute by googling for [vb draw dashed border around textbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb+draw+dashed+border+around+textbox).

Comment: The example on Experts Exchange only shows doing one single textbox Is it possible to do a loop and get every textbox on my form so I don't have to put this code in every paint event for every single textbox. I did post the code above showing that I'm trying to do it to all textboxes not just one.

Comment: You _could_ experiment and find out yourself if you can do it in a loop. Or you could do additional research on your own. Programming is often a process that is metaphorically like assembling Lego(tm) bricks; your question suggested that you were missing a particular brick, and my response showed you where you could find that brick. How to snap them together is up to you, and you need to understand how to do that to truly consider yourself a programmer.

Comment: I don't consider myself a programmer. I do this for fun when and if I ever need a program to do something simple. I did search google before I came here and didn't find what I was looking for. I do feel that my question could have maybe been worded differently. I've very new to coding and it's very hard to me to come up with ways to do things like this on my own. I learn better from examples. My mind doesn't work well when I need to do it myself. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: @JoeBobJr you need to inflate the border to a bit bigger than the size of the control you want to draw around.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin you shouldn't post a link to some site that requires you to create an account.

Comment: @Chillzy - You only have to create an account on Expert's Exchange if you want immediate access (i.e., no 30-second delay) to the accepted answer, or if you want to post to the site. Should I refrain from posting links to other StackExchange sites, too, since you have to create an account for them to participate?

Comment: I agree with Chillzy on this one. You shouldn't be forced to make an account on a website just to read over the website. I couldn't even see the link you posted till I went and registered which is a bit ridiculous. I don't like creating accounts that I won't ever use. I'm not going to pay money to ask a question on that site so why should I have to register just to view the contents? It's non-sense to be honest.

Comment: @JoeBobJr - I don't have an account there, and in order to read the answer, all I had to do was wait about 15 seconds. I know how people feel about paysites; I feel the same way - but if I can get the information I'm seeking without paying, and it's a valid answer, I have no problem with posting the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    For Each txtBox As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (txtBox) Is TextBox Then
            Dim borderRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(txtBox.Location, txtBox.Size)
            borderRectangle.Inflate(1, 1)
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRectangle, txtBox.ForeColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfect I see now. Ty you so much that's exactly what I wanted. Now I can use something like this to do borders on every control if I wish too do so. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason that using this code with Form instead of Textbox will not put a border on the forms?

Comment: I believe I know why I'm trying to set a sub up for each control and calling the sub for each one and I believe it has something to do with the e as painteventargs not allowing multiple controls to be sent to it or something. I'll have to mess around with it.

Comment: you want your border to be redrawn every time you repaint the window.

Comment: works fine with 20 textboxes. if you have textboxes inside panels...I don't think they would loop. you would have to create a loop to go through the panels and look for textboxes inside panels or put the code in the panel paint event

Comment: It worked fine with your code I was just doing something stupid and I ended up figuring it out. Trial and error I guess that's how I learn. lol I'm having another issue though when I drag the form on accident off my screen and bring it back it draws a ton of borders all over the form and the only way I've figured out how to get it back is to do me.refresh() is there a better way than refreshing the form to fix this?

Comment: How many textbox do you have? It might be a video driver update you need. I have no issue on dragging the form.

Comment: My code ended up being wrong. I added a line of code in the loop to add the form border because I was using the Override OnPaint event and I couldn't add it to the form_onpaint event. I ended up figuring it out though thanks for all your help!

Comment: @JoeBobJr no problems bud